# Postback of Form hiding DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, html

I have a contest form that is a usercontrol, it sits on page that has several usercontrols on it. When a user clicks a button it displays this form which resides in usercontrol, the div (which is on the page) is hidden at first. The only problem I am running into is when the page post backs it hides the DIV even when there is an error. I need it to keep the DIV open if there is an error, the code logic for form validation is in the usercontrol so how could I access the DIV that is on the page? The page is a masterpage, we dont do any code logic in our masterpages, is there anyway to accomplish this without code on the masterpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be exposing some property that says if any error occurred on user control or not and setting the Div's visibility on page itself based on that user control property.